# How to describe and format print equivalents

Tags: julia

I am learning Julia by using it as a substitute for R and Python.

I have a Python statement:

```
df = pd.read_csv('{0}/{1:03.0f}.csv'.format(directory, int(id)))
```

and am using

```
filename = length(string(id)) == 1 ? "00"*string(id) : 
           length(string(id)) == 2 ? "0"*string(id) : string(id)
df = readtable(directory*"/"*filename*".csv")
```

I quite like this but is there a simpler way?

Similarly with Python I can get a summary (R) of the dataframes statistics by using df.describe().  Is there an equivalent in Julia yet?

Comment: These kinds of questions (especially two seemingly unrelated ones), might be better asked on the julia-users group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users.

Comment: ok.  will do in future.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@sprintf` macro like this:

```
julia> @sprintf("%s/%03d.csv","foo",1)
"foo/001.csv"
```

You can get a summary of a DataFrame using the `describe` function:

```
julia> using RDatasets

julia> iris = data("datasets","iris");

julia> describe(iris)

Min      1.0
1st Qu.  38.25
Median   75.5
Mean     75.5
3rd Qu.  112.75
Max      150.0
NAs      0
NA%      0.0%

Sepal.Length
Min      4.3
1st Qu.  5.1
Median   5.8
Mean     5.843333333333332
3rd Qu.  6.4
Max      7.9
NAs      0
NA%      0.0%

Sepal.Width
Min      2.0
1st Qu.  2.8
Median   3.0
Mean     3.0573333333333337
3rd Qu.  3.3
Max      4.4
NAs      0
NA%      0.0%

Petal.Length
Min      1.0
1st Qu.  1.6
Median   4.35
Mean     3.758000000000001
3rd Qu.  5.1
Max      6.9
NAs      0
NA%      0.0%

Petal.Width
Min      0.1
1st Qu.  0.3
Median   1.3
Mean     1.1993333333333331
3rd Qu.  1.8
Max      2.5
NAs      0
NA%      0.0%

Species
Length  150
Type    UTF8String
NAs     0
NA%     0.0%
Unique  3
```

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf` is the most compact, but just FYI there's also `lpad` and `rpad`.